# inner query without FROM

Tags: postgresql

I made a mistake when writing the query, I wrote a subquery without a FROM clause:

```
select * from foo where id in (select id where type 'mm')
```

I lost half a day to find a mistake because it worked!

I checked the documentation but I did not find any information why ...

It is more interesting:

```
select * from abc a
inner join abc b on b.id = a.id
where a.id in (select id from (select a.id, row_number () over () lp where b.name = 'abc') x where lp = 1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4bb29/12

Can someone explain how it works?

Comment: why second looks more interesting?

Comment: In normal case with FROM: (select id from (select a.id, row_number () over () lp where b.name = 'abc') x where lp = 1) return 1 record, this query return 2 id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query will certainly **not** work as it is.

To understand your second query, keep in mind that

1. A `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause is like as if there is a `FROM` clause with a table that has no column, but one row.
2. You can reference columns from the outer query in the subquery.

Here is an attempt to explain your query:

```
SELECT * FROM abc a
/* ok, now we have a table with alias "a" */
INNER JOIN abc b ON b.id = a.id
/* now we also have a table with alias "b" */
WHERE a.id IN
   (SELECT id
    FROM (SELECT a.id,
                 /* this will count the one "artificial" row */
                 row_number() OVER () lp
          /* Here you reference the table with alias "b" above.
             This is constant as far as the subquery is concerned,
             so if it is not TRUE, the subquery will return an
             empty result */
          WHERE b.name = 'abc') x
    /* this is always true, since there is only one line in
       the above subquery */ 
    WHERE lp = 1);
```

Comment: You right, i'm missed `in` in first query (post updated)